Why can't multiple sound waves travelling together be polarised?
When there are multiple sound waves/ any longitudinal waves travelling like this, why can't it be polarised?


Your image doesn't really clarify what you mean.

Polarization is a property of transverse waves, where the oscillations of the wave are perpendicular to the direction of propagation. For example, light waves, which are electromagnetic waves, can be polarized.
Longitudinal waves, on the other hand, oscillate parallel to the direction of propagation. Sound waves are a common example of longitudinal waves. Since there's only one direction of oscillation, there's no way to filter or orient these oscillations to achieve polarization.

But I am asking when multiple longitudinal waves [$\implies$ "unpolarised sound wave"] are travelling together

@BallisticCR7 What would a "polarised sound wave" look like ? Remember that the direction of oscillation of a sound wave is always the same as its direction of propagation, whereas a transverse wave (like a light wave or a wave on a skipping rope) can oscillate in any direction that is perpendicular to its direction of propagation.

@gandalf61 Instead of the multiple planes [image in the main question], it will be in a single plane

@BallisticCR7 Point is that once you set the direction of propagation for a longitudinal wave then the oscillations must take place in that same direction - there is no choice about the plane of oscillation, as there is with transverse waves.
